# Array adding new Series Highchart

Tags: php, mysqli, highcharts

This Code just Browser share name series..

```js
series: [{
    name: 'Man',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($man_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>
   
  }, {
    name: 'Women',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($woman_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>

    
  }, {
    name: 'Kind',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($kind_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>
   
  }, {
    name: 'User',
    data:<?php echo json_encode($user_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>
   
  }]
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXrPf.png)

How can create series like series : women, series : man...help me please...

```
//Include Koneksi
$koneksi     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "simcard");
// $bulan       = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT bulan FROM penjualan WHERE tahun='2017' order by id asc");

//Membuat Query
$q=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM penduduk");
$a=mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM card");


$man_array=array();
$woman_array=array();
$kind_array=array();
$user_array=array();
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    $man_array[]= $r["man"];
    $woman_array[]= $r["woman"];
}
while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
    $kind_array[]=$f["kind"];
    $user_array[]= $f["user"];
}
```

this one highchart code any wrong this code..?no used the color no problem.

```js
$('#view').highcharts({
       chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            //stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
```

```js
This Page View source html series.

series: [{
    name: 'Man',
    data: []   
    
  }, {
    name: 'Women',
    data: []
    
  }, {
    name: 'Kind',
     data: []    
  }, {
    name: 'User',
    data:[]   
  }]
  
    });
});
```

Comment: check this [tutorial](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database) and code accordingly. Add comments if facing difficulty

Comment: i have tried it..but didn't work...can you fixed to help me..please...

Comment: can you edit the existing series what you are expecting. It Is difficult to understand what is written at present

Comment: i have revision...but series can't show.

Comment: you can see this image just one colour or series.https://pasteboard.co/fhSqTzyRJ.png

Comment: so tell me about  `$r["man"]` ,`$r["women"]`,`$f["kind"]`,`$f["user"]` how it is part of series. In current screenshot it is only single data is populating

Comment: screenshoot just one series and the colour blue..i want man colour red, women colour black just like that..so i have 4 series in highchart with series man,series women,series kind series user and 4 colour each..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your chart will come like this,[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5891r5pe/). So replace with code below. Also check [Data from a database](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database)

```
<?php
    $man_array=array();
    $woman_array=array();
    $kind_array=array();
    $user_array=array();
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
        $man_array[]= $r["man"];
        $woman_array[]= $r["woman"];
    }
    while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($a)){
        $kind_array[]=$f["kind"];
        $user_array[]= $f["user"];
    }

    ?>
  series: [{
    name: 'Man',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($man_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>,
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    name: 'Women',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($woman_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>,

    color: 'black'
  }, {
    name: 'Kind',
    data: <?php echo json_encode($kind_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>,
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    name: 'User',
    data:<?php echo json_encode($user_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>,
    color: 'blue'
  }]
```

Comment: thanks but highchart blank or no data show...?see new revision of connection mysql on top...that is correcly..?

Comment: use `echo intval($f["user"])."',";`

Comment: echo intval($f["user"])."',";  still same no data show.

Comment: still same blank highchart...see source highchart on the top update..no matter the color.any wrong with the code..?

Comment: can you verify with right click an view page source how the array is forming in  series: [{}]  script code in html page

Comment: code you have added above is incomplete , add series to it. why you are not using my fiddle sample and replace this php code over there

Comment: see update on top page view source html series...done i have used fiddle sample..but stil same not data show..see screenshoot https://pasteboard.co/1xfJ09Yak.bmp that is used fiddle sample.i have changed code on top used fiddle sample.

Comment: add **view page source** of code in https://pastebin.com/ . add the correct one color is missing in your view source page

Comment: can you add result of `<?php echo json_encode($man_array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ;exit;?>`

Comment: ahh thanks very much...i have wrong name array..thank you..this code is working now..thank you...